# How to add prop/value dynamically to kendo columns

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

After initialization

```
<div kendo-grid="grid" k-options="vm.gridOptions" k-columns="vm.columns" ng-show="vm.filtered"></div>
```

JS:

```
vm.columns = [
  {
    field: 'client',
    title: 'Client',
    attributes: { 'class': 'k-gridRow' }
  },
  {
    field: 'total',
    title: 'Total',
    attributes: { 'class': 'text-right' },
    format: '{0:n0}',
    width: 110
............
```

I need to add/change to column total footerTemplate with new values after some events on page

I tried `vm.columns[3]['footerTemplate'] = '2333';` but it is not working.
Help please , maybe reinit for this column only at least, this bad variant though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`setOptions()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setOptions) method to change any widget options after initialization. Try this:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var columns = grid.getOptions().columns; // Get the columns from getOptions()

// Change whatever you like
columns[1].footerTemplate = "Min: (#: min #) - Max: (#: max #)";

// Set only columns options again
grid.setOptions({
    columns: columns
});
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EPIRe)

Comment: into the vm.gridOptions.dataSource.data() is contained items, after grid.setOptions({ their disappire

Comment: @YuriySadovoy well, then try to add the whole options object again instead of just the columns.. something like: `var options = grid.getOptions(); options.columns[1].footerTemplate = "Min: (#: min #) - Max: (#: max #)"; grid.setOptions(options)`;

Comment: it's strange, coz vm.gridOptions.dataSource has all data but grid hides them

Comment: @YuriySadovoy can you create a demo in dojo.telerik.com with your case ?

Comment: after setOption i tried to read again vm.gridOptions.dataSource.read(); , not worked

Comment: @YuriySadovoy try creating a simple grid with like yours with essential params and use static part of data, it would be helpful.

Comment: code is valid and on may WebStrom code is Building. I found problem, it is double query to readData2(db in my case), for me it's so bad( but setOptions() works very good i mean method change value but when put this property : autoBind: false, ellements hides after setOptions(), if autoBind: false is absent then code do double query = (

Comment: @YuriySadovoy I do see query, but I can't your grid to work, so I can't help solving your issue...